# Multiple (optional) one to one Relationships with single navigation property

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I'm trying to configure a relationship between two entities where the parent can have multiple (named) childs from the same type while the child should only have one generic parent.
Based on the Blog/Posts example I'm trying to configure the following. Blogposts aren't a good example but in my application I have 5 fixed child entities.

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public int? FirstPostId { get; set; }
    public Post FirstPost { get; set; }

    public int? SecondPostId { get; set; }
    public Post SecondPost { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int? BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to configure this like:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Blog>()
    .HasOne(_ => _.FirstPost)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Blog>(_ => _.FirstPostId);
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Blog>()
    .HasOne(_ => _.SecondPost)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Blog>(_ => _.SecondPostId);
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Post>()
    .HasOne(_ => _.Blog)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Post>(_ => _.BlogId);
```

In my real world problem a Post additionally does not need to belong to a Blog and all foreign keys are composite keys but that should be no problem.

Configured like that FirstPost and SecondPost are recognized but Post.Blog/Post.BlogId is always null.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: In relational database, when you refer to something via FK like your `FirstPostId`, `SecondPostId`, the thing you are referring to is not a child (dependent), but parent (principal). Thus `Post.BlogId` makes no any sense, and of course `Post.Blog` navigation cannot be mapped to 2 and more relationships, so the whole thing cannot be mapped. Fixed count or not, if `Post` is a child, then you should have `ICollection<Post>` in parent, and have some property of `Post` telling whether it is first, second, etc.

Comment: Thx, I was hoping to not need that Collection on Blog and the additional property on Post but seems like it's not that easy. 
Nevertheless as an alternative I'm thinking about inheriting FirstPost/SecondPost/... from Post to avoid that collection and let ef handle the discriminator on the other hand. That might come closer to my needs.